# Phonegap Build - No App Icon on Device

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a small mobile app that was uploaded to Phonegap Build to bundle the app for different platform, I only insterested in the android bundle for now.

The challenge is after uploading the app and phonegap gives the apk I install on my device, the icon to launch the app on the device is the generic phonegap icon, I already added this to my config file and the files are in place correctly in the icon folder

```
<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon/icon.png" />
<icon src="icon/icon_036.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="icon/icon_048.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="icon/icon_072.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
```

I also observed that on opening the apk with winrar in the res folder I still have the default phonegap icon in place while my splash screen has been updated and working on device normally.

Is there anything I am missing??

Comment: On PhoneGap Build it's written default icon must be named exactly "icon.png" (that file must be of course a real PNG image), located at the root (ie next to your index.html and config.xml file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. Please see if your `config.xml` file is in the same folder as `index.html` and in that same folder you make a separate folder named `img` and place `icon.png` in that folder. You are also making the mistake of not giving icon a default tag:

```
<icon src="img/icon.png" gap:role="default" />
```

give it a try!

Comment: Hi Monika, I think index.html file is mostly in www folder and config.xml is in root folder ( one folder below www ). this is reference from default hello app of phoengap how can they be in same folder

Answer (score 0):

Go into your *ProjectRoot->platforms->android->res* directory

Iterate through each folder and replace "icon.png" with your custom icon image that is of the equivalent sizing.

Finally, in your root **config.xml** file, add:

`<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>`

beneath the author property.

HTH