# Phonegap icon isn't showing

Tags: cordova

I have my phonegap app and in my config.xml I have [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world/blob/master/template_src/www/config.xml). The problem is that the icon isn't the icon I chose for the app, it's the cordova logo...

Comment: what is the platform you are using?

Comment: I am using Android 5.0, there was a question like mine but it is old and the config.xml is different : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901059/phonegap-build-no-app-icon-on-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons are located in the `res/` folder in the root of the apk. In your config you specify the location of each icon to be in the res folder as a subfolder of the `www/` directory. This is probably why the application can't find the icon and the default Cordova icon is displayed.

So try removing all `www/` prefixes from all of your icon src's:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon   src="res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"               density="ldpi" />
    <icon   src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"               density="mdpi" />
    ...
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all lines related with icon src by a path to your new logo.(Only under the android xml tag)

> ```
> <icon   src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"               density="ldpi" />
>         <icon   src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"               density="mdpi" />
>         <icon   src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"               density="hdpi" />
>         <icon   src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"              density="xhdpi" />
>         <icon   src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"
> ```

Comment: you need to change all icons as there are lot of icons called drawable-mdpi-icon.png  , drawable-xhdpi-icon.png etc.Those icons are stored in the www/res/icon/android/ directory.

Comment: give it a try making a new folder and saving images there

Comment: I don't think it will help but OK

Comment: The same as the github one